# Laravel, get data of a specific column from table and store it in a different column name in another table

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables, the first one looks like this:

```
Id   Name   Email           Password
1    Jack   Jack@gmail.com  Ksecneidsw54?

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('password');
            }
```

The second one is empty:

```
Id   Username

Schema::create('join_public', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username');
            $table->timestamps();
        }
```

I want to copy the Name for example (Jack) from the first table and put it in column {Username}  in the second table.

It should look like this

```
Id   Username
1    Jack
```

How can I go about doing so?

Comment: explain more please. share schema as well and code.

Comment: @r89human I did. I just need to copy one specific value to another table, something like the function replicate but for one value.

Comment: are you using models or nothing?

Comment: Yes, I'm using models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not using Models.

```
$user = DB::table("users")->where('name', '=', 'Jack')->first();
DB::table('join_public')->insert(['username' => $user->name]);
```

if you are using models then

```
$user = User::where('name', '=', 'Jack')->first();
JoinPublic::create(['username' => $user->name]);
```

and add this line in model JoinPublic

```
protected $table = 'join_public';
protected $fillable = ['username'];
```